# TabView in SwiftUI not responding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make an app using the TabView. The app renders and runs nicely, except for the fact that tapping on the tabs does nothing.

Here is my code, am I missing something?

```
TabView {
    HomeView()
        .tabItem {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                Text("Home")
            }
        }.tag(1)
    SecondView()
        .tabItem {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                Text("SecondView")
            }
        }.tag(2)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, in the end it turned out I had the accessibility option "Full keyboard access" turned on. Switching this off fixed it.

Comment: Holy cr••. This would have taken me ages to figure out! Thx!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example which works fine for me:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Home")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondView")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }.tag(1)
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                        Text("SecondView")
                    }
            }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: for somereason this doesn't work for me. I even created a fresh project. And pasted your code. Still doesnot work. Maybe my Xcode has gone nuts

Comment: I am using the latest version. Version 11.2.1 (11B500)

Comment: that's odd! For me this works perfectly in Simulator and on my iPhone... maybe it's a completely different issue! Re-install Xcode?

Comment: It works now. Rebooting my machine is what fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

The example from krjw worked for me, but i wanted to show an example with the best practices from Apple (e.g. using a Label instead of an Image & Text in a Vstack) and showing the .badge modifier.

I know when i started out I liked to have the *entire* code to copy and paste so i included everything in my file.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ReceivedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Received")
    }
}

struct SentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sent")
    }
}

struct AccountView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Account")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ReceivedView()
                .badge(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Received", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")
                }
            SentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Sent", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.up.fill")
                }
            AccountView()
                .badge("!")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Account", systemImage: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```